# Categories and Items for Codeigniter Query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how I can do this Codeigniter ActiveRecord query so that my returned results will be what I'm desiring.

I have a menu_categories table and a menu_categories_items table. The structure is as follows.

```
menu_categories
    -category_id (pk autoinc)
    -category_name
    -category_class

menu_categories_items
    -item_id (pk autoinc)
    -item_name
    -category_id (fk)
```

I have so far been able to retrieve the correct result object from the db that shows up as this.

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (3) {
        ["category_id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["category_name"]=> string(9) "Dashboard"
        ["category_class"]=> string(9) "dashboard"
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#24 (3) {
        ["category_id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["category_name"]=> string(5) "Users"
        ["category_class"]=> string(5) "users"
    }
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#24 (3) {
        ["category_id"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["category_name"]=> string(5) "Pages"
        ["category_class"]=> string(5) "pages"
        /* HOW I WANT IT TO LOOK IN THE OBJECT */
        ["links"]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (2) {
                ["item_id"]=> string(1) "1"
                ["item_name"]=> string(5) "Admin Pages"
            [1]=> object(stdClass)#24 (2) {
                ["item_id"]=> string(1) "2"
                ["item_name"]=> string(5) "User Pages"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say the Pages category has other items that make up the category. I'm trying to figure out how I should finish the rest of the query. I thought about doing a join and selecting the fields that belong with the categories. Or should I be doing some sort of subquery or what is the the suggested route.

EDIT:

For some reason I"m getting the white screen of death.

```
$x = 0;
    if($this->general_functions->null_check($dashboard_menu_categories) == TRUE){$x++;}

    if ($x == 0)
    {
        foreach($dashboard_menu_categories as $category){
            $items = $this->db->get_where('dashboard_menu_categories_items', array('category_id' => $category->category_id));
            if($items->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $dashboard_menu_categories['links'] = $items->result();
            }
        }
        return $dashboard_menu_categories;
    }
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($dashboard_menu_categories); 
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I don't know if you've seen my update but I've included what I"m desiring. If the category has links it'll add an array under the category like demonstrated above with the a few fields.

Comment: item_id and link_id are same?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry let me adjust that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data=yourFunctionToGetCategory_menu

foreach($data as $m){
$l=$this->db->get_where('menu_categories_items',array('category_id'=>$m->category_id));
if($l->num_rows>0){
$data[]=$l->result();
}
}return $data;
```

Comment: ok then u solved ur problem by ur self yes? So post your answer and accept your answer

Comment: Call to a member function get_where() on a non-object

Comment: when u return something. if return is executed no further codes will run if you want to see your data put var_dump in place of return.

Comment: your table's name is menu_categories_items yes?? then what is it dashboard_menu_categories_items?